# all zero one sequences where ones aren't next to each other

Tags: algorithm, binary, combinations, procedure

I've got to write a procedure which for every given n>0 writes down every single 0-1 sequence of lenght n, where 1 can't sit next to any other 1.

For example: for n=3 the output is:

000, 001, 010, 100, 101

I thought about recursion but can't see any use of it in this case.

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For n=3 it looks like you have 2^3-3 outcomes. See if its the same for n=4 and maybe go from there

Comment: Assuming I didn't do anything wrong, for n=4 i get 8 numbers and for n=5 there are 13 of them, kinda seems like it's connected with Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 2):

Just exclude the result, which have consecutive 1s .
Below is the sample java Code :

```
public class Test0 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int n = 4;
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2,n); i++) {

            if ( (i & (i << 1)) != 0 )
                continue;
            System.out.println( i/8 % 2 + "" + i/4 % 2 + "" + i/2 % 2 + "" + i % 2);
        }
    }
}
```

If there is two consecutiv 1s, expression `i & (i << 1))` will result in non-zero, otherwise 0.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a hint and you mentioned recursion, here's a recursive hint:

```
0 -> can precede either 1 or 0
  -> 01
  -> 00

1 -> can precede 0
  -> 10

01 -> 010
00 -> 000
      001
10 -> 100
      101
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python recursive solution:

```
def rec(n,a=''):
    if len(a)==n:
        print a
        return
    rec(n,a+'0')
    if len(a)==0 or a[-1]!='1':
        rec(n,a+'1')

rec(3)
```

prints:

```
000
001
010
100
101
```

It actually turns out by [Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) that the n^th term in this sequence is equal to the Zeckendorf representation (which expresses numbers in terms of Fibonacci terms) of the number n.  This explains why the number of choices is given by the Fibonacci numbers.